# Losing session variable, classic asp, iis7, url rewrite ie 10 & 11

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, url-rewriting, session-variables, internet-explorer-10

This is the strangest problem and is driving me crazy.

We had an online questionnaire and I decided to split it up as opposed to having it in one long form.

The form submits to the same page, at the top of the page it checks which page it is on, reads in the data from the previous page and stores it in a session variable (an array). There are also a couple more session variables that sum up the answers etc.

It reads in the data perfectly but when the page is submitted again the session seems to lose the previous data and only has the newer information.

This is the curious bit. It works perfectly in chrome, firefox, safari and older versions of ie.

It also works in ie10 / 11 when i browse directly to the page e.g. questionnaire.asp but when I access the page via a url rewrite /questionnaire/stage-1 it fails to hold the session variables but again only in ie10 and 11.

This is driving me crazy. I can see any issues in the code so I feel it is something else maybe relating to how ie works with session variables with iis7 / url rewrite!

Going mad here!

Thanks

Comment: In the rewrite rules, are you removing the WWW prefix, changing to a sub-domain, switching to and from HTTP/HTTPS or anything that changes the URL?

Comment: no, nothing like that. At the moment it's all on a sub domain as it's just a prototype and like I said it works perfectly using other browsers. So strange.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to set the expiration time of session variables.

Try code below:

```
<% Session.Timeout=120 %>
```

*That is in minutes.*

Comment: Even with this setting it will still reset it when I view it via the url rewrite link.

To add to above there are other session variables that are already created before this page and they stay intact!

One of the session variables I am creating on this page an using is an array. Could that be affecting it for some strange reason?

Comment: I see. Maybe you can consider trying other way like storing it in a temp table in your database before inserting it to the final table.